# Recursively Assigning One List Element to Another in Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

This is a homework assignment and my first experience with Prolog. My goal is to create a list of Assignments from a list of people and a list of tasks. If a person has the letter identifier which matches the tasks then that persons ID and the Tasks ID are matched up and placed in a list of Assignments. My function prints out a list but it does not look like it is comparing all the elements. A sample input: schedule([p1,p2,p3],[t1,t2],Result). A sample output would look like [[p1,t1],[p2,t2][p3,t1],[p3,t2]].

What I have so far:

```
%%
%% person(ID, TASK_CAPABILITIES, AVAILABLE_HOURS)
%%
%%   How many hours each person has available and what classes of tasks they
%%   are capable of performing.
%%
person(p1, [c,a], 20).
person(p2, [b], 10).
person(p3, [a,b], 15).
person(p4, [c], 30).
%%
%% task(ID, REQUIRED_HOURS, TASK_CLASS)
%%
%%   How long each task requires and what class it falls under.
%%
task(t1, a, 5).
task(t2, b, 10).
task(t3, c, 15).
task(t4, c, 10).
task(t5, a, 15).
task(t6, b, 10).

%test arithmetic functions
add(X, Y, Z) :- Z is X + Y.
subtract(X,Y,Z) :- Z is X - Y.


schedule([],[],[]).
schedule(People,
 [Task|OtherTasks],
[[PersonId, TaskId]|RestOfAssignments]):-
  member(PersonId, People),
  person(PersonId, PersonCapabilities,_),
  member(TaskId, [Task|OtherTasks]),
  task(TaskId, TaskType,_),
  member(TaskType, PersonCapabilities),
  schedule( _, OtherTasks, RestOfAssignments).
```

My reasoning behind what I wrote was that the list of People would be compared to each task, then that task would be replaced by the next task and the comparison would repeat. What I see in the trace of this function instead is that the tasks are being removed from the list but are only compared to the first two People. My question is how can I get the schedule function to check the full list of people for each task?

Comment: If you query `schedule([p1,p2,p3],[t1,t2],Result)` then why does the expected result contain `t5` and `t6`? I'm not sure I understand the meaning of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems ill specified, and you are simplifying too much... the code should keep into account hours availability as well as memberships. Ignoring this problem, select/3 instead of member/2 could help to model a naive solution:

```
schedule([],_,[]).
% peek a suitable task for PersonId
schedule([PersonId|People], Tasks, [[PersonId, TaskId]|RestOfAssignments]):-
  select(TaskId, Tasks, RestTasks),
  person(PersonId, PersonCapabilities,_),
  task(TaskId, TaskType,_),
  memberchk(TaskType, PersonCapabilities),
  schedule(People, RestTasks, RestOfAssignments).
% if no suitable task for PersonId
schedule([_PersonId|People], Tasks, Assignments):-
  schedule(People, Tasks, Assignments).
```

yields these solutions

```
?- schedule([p1,p2,p3],[t1,t2],Result).
Result = [[p1, t1], [p2, t2]] ;
Result = [[p1, t1], [p3, t2]] ;
Result = [[p1, t1]] ;
Result = [[p2, t2], [p3, t1]] ;
Result = [[p2, t2]] ;
Result = [[p3, t1]] ;
Result = [[p3, t2]] ;
Result = [].
```

Comment: Hi, could you help me understand why all the results are not on one line? Or more specifically what is happening when you use the or ; during the query?

Comment: ';' means 'please, get me the next available solution'. That is, start backtracking. It's used on the command line, *after* a query succeeded.